# Traveling From India to Barbados - outside India's air-transport bubble

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, barbados

I'm an Indian citizen living in India and fully vaccinated with WHO-approved vaccine.

India has [air transport bubble for international flights](https://www.civilaviation.gov.in/en/about-air-transport-bubbles). I'm planning to travel from India to Barbados for a week which is outside this bubble. The flight would most probably be from the UK, which is inside the bubble.

Is it allowed to make this journey as I'll be leaving and entering India from a country within a bubble?

Comment: Not enough information. What is your arrival airport in the UK? What is your departure airport from the UK? How much time is between flight arrival and flight departure? During your trip, will you stop/pass through/layover in an other country or countries?

Comment: Technically speaking, India has no means to prevent you from traveling to Barbados from the UK, and under international law probably can't stop you from coming back into India if you are an Indian citizen. The legality and practicality of the trip may, however, be in question.

Comment: Yes. The issue here is not getting out of India, the issues are transiting in the UK, both directions, and then being readmitted into India. Answering will require knowing more than the OP has yet disclosed.

Comment: Looks like this won't be an issue now as India has resumed commercial international flights - https://twitter.com/DGCAIndia/status/1501179980910239744?s=20&t=lL1P-T9Ioc7kqmsCv8f_DA

Answer (score 4):

Per the guidelines you yourself link to, bubble flights to the UK are supposed to be for:

> Any Indian national holding any type of valid UK visa and destined for UK only.

If you do not hold a visa for the UK, you will thus not be allowed to board.  Even if you do hold a UK visa, you may experience problems if your itinerary indicates you're only transiting instead of being destined to "UK only".

However, if you do have a UK visa that allows multiple entries, I don't see anything that would stop you from booking one India-UK "bubble" roundtrip and nesting a UK-Barbados roundtrip within that. It's not clear to me if you're supposed/"allowed" to do this, but that's a separate question.

All that said, given how difficult travel continues to be these days, I suspect you would find it much easier and cheaper to travel to a tropical bubble destination like the Maldives or the Seychelles instead, since both can be reached on direct flights and travel to both is 100% permitted.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica These are Indian regulations and OP is Indian, so "foreign nationals" does not apply to them.

Comment: Ouch, you're absolutely right. Thanks. I'll delete my comment.